# err_address_unreachable : Cannot reach websites except some

Tags: macos, catalina, dns, internet

I'm running on macOS Catalina. The Wi-Fi at my work was reset and now I can connect to internet but only Google Gmail and a few other big companies' websites load, no others.

I tried manually setting my DNS to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4, I tried the `sudo kill mDNSResponder`. I've tried renew DHCP lease. And of course restarting the computer. Nothing has worked does anyone have any other suggestions. I'm pretty sure it's a DNS problem because the error I get in Chrome is "err_address_unreachable"

Comment: You should probably talk to the IT staff where you work.

Comment: Let’s do some diagnostics.  Post the output of `dig apple.com`  Mostly interested in the output at the end, but post the whole output to your question